# 2 different unix time stamp is generated when JSR223 Pre Processor is used in Jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, unix-timestamp

Here is the groovy code used in Jmeter JSR223 preprocessor:

```
import java.lang.Long
def long timeStamp=System.currentTimeMillis();
def name=("Report_"+timeStamp);
log.info(name)
vars.put("DocumentName",name);
```

I need to generate the first hit timestamp(single) and pass it to 2 different transaction. But when I checked jmeter log, it has 2 different timestamp that has been passed to 2 different transaction.

The same I have checked with SOAPUI tool but it gives me single output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you place Pre processor according to Jmeter [scoping rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
2. If you keep [JSR223 Pre processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) to the test plan level, it will be called before each sampler, thats the reason why you are getting different values..
3. remove Pre processor from thread group/ test plan level and keep it as a child of the first sampler in transaction 1. so that Pre processor executed only once. as shown below.
   For more information on advanced JMeter scripting please follow [this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/4878/)

[image]

You can see in the results tree same value is being passed

[image]

Comment: It worked. I was doing the mentioned mistake. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I tried but vote cast by members less than 15 reputation are recorded but not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to avoid scripting where possible as [native Java code in any case performs better than any scripting language](https://www.blazemeter.com/ja/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance), in your case you can achieve what you need using JMeter's built-in [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time)

[image: JMeter Generate Timestamp time function]

Comment: Thanks for input.